# How to scrape a specific itemprop from a web page with XPath and Selenium?

Tags: selenium, web-scraping, xpath, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to use Python (Selenium, BeautifulSoup, and XPath) to scrape a span with an itemprop equal to "description", but every time I run the code, the "try" fails and it prints out the "except" error.

I do see the element in the code when I inspect elements on the page.

Line that isn't getting the desired response:

```
quick_overview = soup.find_element_by_xpath("//span[contains(@itemprop, 'description')]")
```

Answer (score 3):

Personally, I think you should just keep working with selenium

```
quick_overview = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[contains(@itemprop, 'description')]")
```

for the element and add  `.text` to end to get the text content.

To actually use soup to parse this out you would likely need a wait condition from selenium first so no real point.

However, should you decide to integrate bs4 then you need to change your function to work with the actual html from driver.page_source and parse that, then switch to select_one to grab your item. Then ensure you are returning from the function and assigning to new soup object.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver # links w/ browser and carries out actions
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

PATH = "C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe"
baseurl = "http://www.waytekwire.com"
skus_to_find_test = ['WL16-8', 'WG18-12']

driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)
driver.get(baseurl)

def use_driver_current_html(driver):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'lxml')
    return soup

for sku in skus_to_find_test[0]:
    
    search_bar = driver.find_element_by_id('themeSearchText')
    search_bar.send_keys(sku)
    search_bar.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)   

    try:
        
        product_url = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[contains(@class, 'itemDescription')]//h3//a[contains(text(), sku)]")[0]
        product_url.click()
        WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//span[contains(@itemprop, 'description')]")))
        soup = use_driver_current_html(driver)
        
        try:
            quick_overview = soup.select_one("span[itemprop=description]").text
            print(quick_overview)
        except:
            print('No Quick Overview Found.')
            
    except:
        print('Product not found.')
```